# HLS Playlist issue "Unable to instantiate decoder OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC" React native video player

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-video, expo-av

I try to play HLS video in flatlist in that some video play and some video through Unable to instantiate decoder OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC , Same video after closing and reopen the app its play good, when we scroll above 15 to 20 videos again it's through the error

```
<Video
id={uuid.v4()}
ref={ref => {
this.video = ref;
}}
source={{
uri:"https://vz-602a2693-e0f.b-cdn.net/c496b51c-8216-4c71-9935-d158caf8a26a/playlist.m3u8"
}}
style={[styles.fullScreen, {height: '100%'}]}
rate={this.state.rate}
//paused={this.state.paused}
paused={this.state.paused}
// useNativeControls
volume={this.state.volume}
muted={this.state.muted}
resizeMode={this.state.resizeMode}
onLoad={this.onLoad}
onProgress={this.onProgress}
progressUpdateInterval={250.0} //IOS
onEnd={this.onEnd}
onAudioBecomingNoisy={this.onAudioBecomingNoisy}
onAudioFocusChanged={this.onAudioFocusChanged}
onLayout={
this.props.onLayout
}
repeat={false}
fullscreenOrientation="portrait"
fullscreen={false}
poster={thumbnail}
posterResizeMode="cover"
controls={false}
onError={this.onError}
playInBackground={false}
disableFocus={false}
playWhenInactive={false}
onBuffer={
this.videoBuffer
}
reportBandwidth={false}
bufferConfig={{
minBufferMs: 5000,
maxBufferMs: 10000,
bufferForPlaybackMs: 2500,
bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs: 5000,
}}
/>
```

Error :

> {"error": {"errorException": "com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(2, null, null, video/avc, avc1.4D401F, 1400000, null, [842, 474, -1.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES", "errorString": "Unable to instantiate decoder OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC"}}

Comment: Did you found any solution to this?